# Syncmode = full, and still getting "missing trie node"

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, synchronization, rpc

I'm running on Rinkeby testnet with this command (I resynced the whole blockchain with this):

```
./geth --rinkeby --syncmode full --rpc --rpcapi "web3,db,eth,net,personal" --datadir /.../
```

and after the whole blockchain synced, I tried (again) to run this command:

I made this call:

```
{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"0x70a082310000000000000000000000004493b159852734e0112c2EfB4FB4aa3aBfb4827a","from":"0x4493b159852734e0112c2EfB4FB4aa3aBfb4827a","to":"0x7b1ad75e80606bc33ee19d7028290b14391429b6"}
,"0x186A0"]}
```

The block number there is an arbitrary number, 100000 (in hex). The call is to get the balance of some arbitrary token.

And received the error `missing trie node`.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the balance very far into the past and it does not exist because you didn't download it. `geth` 1.8 only has 128 StateDB entries, while `geth 1.7.3` has 10,000 , you can only query recent state entries.

Comment: What do you mean with "you didn't download it"? Is there something I can do download it? Btw I have geth 1.8.11. Are you telling me it's hopeless and impossible to query such old blocks?

Comment: I mean , not you, but `geth` didn't recalculate blocks from 0, and downloaded the state of only recent block. It is possible, but it is weeks of processing and terabyte in SSD storage